# How to show OpenGL in PictureBox in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, opengl, mfc, picturebox

I want to show OpenGL processes in Windows Form PictureBox.
I am using Visual C++.
I'm taking user values on Windows Form Interface and I must draw chart for this values.
Do you know any document or sample?

Comment: please help me. My project is working in Win32 application but ı cant to in Windows Forms

Answer (score 0):

I never use Windows Form, but if you're using native Win32 Window, you can create openGL context using hdc of that window, and during creation of that window you should create it with openGL canvas flag. I hope it help.